# Excel VBA browser scraping loop: Reload page for each loop

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am having a bit trouble when web scraping, basically I have a loop that goes to a website and searches for a specific company and clicks on search and then goes to the company page and extracts the company's founding date. (https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx). I basically have a large table but I have a smaller one here for simplicity, and the loop goes from top to bottom of the table in excel and extracts the founding date in the B column next to the name.
{[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zge6F.png)}. My code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub click_search()
Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim output As Range
Dim txt_input As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n As Integer


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True
i.Navigate "https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx"

Do While i.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Set idoc = i.Document

On Error Resume Next
For n = 1 To 3


idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_frmEntityName").Value = Cells(n, 1).Value
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").click
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:15 AM#
idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rptSearchResults_ctl00_lnkbtnEntityName").click
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:10 AM#

Dim V As Variant
Set V = idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblIncDate")
Cells(n, 2) = V.innerHTML

i.Quit
Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True
i.Navigate "https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx"
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:10 AM#


Next n

End Sub
```

The problem is that I have to quit internet explorer and restart it in order to be able to search for the next company, this is where I have a problem in my loop as it just works for the very first iteration and kind of gets stuck on the page in the second iteration of the loop. It works as intended and gets the correct date for the first company but for the second company it kind of gets stuck on the start page and wont search at all. Just reloading the page wont work either as that will cause the browser to get stuck because you have to manually accept that you want to reload the page in the browser. Any help at all on how to fix this issue is greatly  appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: VBA is not the best tool for web scraping because it uses IE and is prone to many problems. I would recommend using a well developed library so you can learn from the mistakes of all who came before you instead of having to go through each problem here on SO, one question at a time. EXAMPLE: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: I managed to solve it by simply removing the last big chunk of the code at i.Quit and replacing it with: 
`i.GoBack
i.Navigate "https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx"
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#
idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_frmEntityName").Value = Cells(n + 2, 1).Value
`

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and select it as the correct answer. That will close this question and it will earn you points!

Comment: you don't need i.GoBack if using i.Navigate again. You don't want to quit an application why you are still using it which is why you want quit outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the last big chunk of the code at i.Quit and replaced it with:

```
i.Navigate "https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx"
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:10 AM#
```